# JNI, Mulithreading and calling methods

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, servlets, java-native-interface

I'm trying to do the following (not sure if I'm missing something or if this is not possible):

I have a Java class (in this particular case a Servlet) that calls a native method.

In this native method I'm spawning a new thread, and in that thread I would like to call a method on that Java object. Is that even possible?

What I tried in the native method that is called (original thread) is to remember the JavaVM instance, so that I can later can attach the other thread to it (seems to work), and make a NewGlobal ref for the jobject:

```
    JavaVM *vm;
env->GetJavaVM(&vm);

env->NewGlobalRef(jobj)
```

What I don't know is how to retrieve the jobject in the other thread. If I just pass it the VM crashes, I assume because of an illegal thread access. If I create a new object for the class, I wouldn't have the exact object that I need.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Mark

SOME ADDITIONAL CODE (method names etc. obscured):

```
The method that is called from the servlet:

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL ABC (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, some more arguments
{
  JavaVM *vm;
  env->GetJavaVM(&vm);
  env->NewGlobalRef(jobj);

  // spawning new thread (I'm using boost libraries)
  boost::thread t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&XYZ::DEF, instance of XYZ, vm, &jobj);
  ...
}

void XYZ::DEF(JavaVM* vm, jobject* jobj)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    vm->GetEnv( (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_2);
    vm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    ... then eventually calling another method, but still the same thread, where I'm doing this:

jobject bb = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(...,...); // this crashed when I just used the env from the original thread, seems to work since I'm attaching the second thread to the VM.

// it crashes somewhere during the following code:
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(jobj);
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "callback", "(I)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(jobj, mid, 13);
```

The crash produces something like this "A fatal error has been detected by the JRE... Problematic frame: V [libjvm.so+0x3e9220]...

Comment: you are calling AttachCurrentThread and using the env pointer returned aren't you?

Comment: @mcnicholls: yes. After that I do a GetObjectClass, using the jobject instance that I remembered from the original thread, which I'm also using when I do a env->CallVoidMehtod(jobj,...) where env is what was returned when calling AttachCurrentThread.

Comment: Can you show more code? What you're doing sounds right; the global reference can be used by any thread, until you delete it.

Comment: I think you should be able to hold onto the jobject Global ref and use it between threads. Can you post your code?

Comment: Thank you. I added some additional code. Your comments already help a bit, because I didn't know if this approach was actually supposed to work, so I will look for some other possible causes for the crash as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be ignoring the result of `NewGlobalRef`. You have to use its result in the other thread instead of the original jobj.